# How to create a resizable emulator in Android Studio Chipmunk

Tags: android, mobile, emulation, resizable, android-studio-chipmunk

With the Android Studio Chipmunk release 2021.2.1 it should be possible to create a **resizable emulator** as it is described here: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/12L/get#resizable-emulator.

But I am unsure how to create one. Where can I find the *resizable device definition* in the Device Manager? There is no such button, as you can see in my screenshot below. I also checked the Hardware Profile and the System Image section, but I could simply not find it.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just upgraded everything this morning (2022-07-13), and now "Resizable" is an option in the "Choose a device definition" page of Android Device Manager.

*"everything":* Android Emulator 31.2.10 would seem to be the relevant update.

[image: device definition page, showing a Resizable device]

Note that on the next page you can only select Sv2 or API 33 as system images.

Comment: Here's some android docs about the resizable emulator: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/12L/get#resizable-emulator

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it without any problem by creating a new device. You may also be able to change the hardware profile on a device you've previously created. But there isn't a simple "Resizable device" checkbox in the options to make your current device resizable. You need to select a hardware profile that was designed to be resizable.

Comment: "You need to select a hardware profile that was designed to be resizable." ... such as?

Comment: Such as the one you have selected in the image on the answer you created. Glad you got it figured out.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe In new Android Studio version you can select the "Resizable" option in the hardware options menu.